# Convert 4:3 to 16:9 like QuickTime Panoramic Size

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime, aspect, scale

QuickTime has an awesome feature called "Panoramic Size". It basically scales the input video to the screen aspect ratio **without cropping** by leaving the center as-is and gradually increasing the scale factor towards the sides.

It’s a quite unique feature as far as I can tell, as I’ve only ever seen it in QuickTime.

It can be activated like this ([Apple Guide here](https://support.apple.com/guide/quicktime-player/choose-a-screen-size-qtp31dfa136d/mac)):

[image: QuickTime Panoramic View]

What I’m looking for is any way to permanently use the same or a similar algorithm to re-encode some 4:3 videos into 16:9, so that they show correctly on all my devices, not just the ones using QuickTime.

### 4:3 input example:

[image: example 4:3 image]

> just for ease of comparison

### Naïve 16:9 crop:

[image: 16:9 crop of a 4:3 video]

> as you can see, there’s quite a lot of content missing top and bottom

### Naïve 16:9 scale:

[image: naive scale of 16:9 video]

> as you can see, the circle barely looks like a circle anymore and a lot of content will look odd, especially faces

### QuickTime 16:9 panoramic mode results:

[image: 16:9 scaled via QuickTime Panoramic Mode]

> pretty good, if you ask me — that’s why I want to re-encode like this.
> the sides are stretched much more than the center, which usually yields good results as the center is the most important part of the screen
> this is actually why I chose a scene with a clearly visible circle — which stays nearly unchanged thanks to QuickTime magic

---

So, what can I do to accomplish this? Only way I can think of is making a screen recording, which would take hours and is very error-prone

Comment: Do you have After Effects?

Comment: @stib Not currently, but if you know how to do it then in the spirit of Stackoverflow it would still be a good answer, as it could help someone else trying to accomplish this. Also, depending on how good the results are, I may just buy or get a free trial for After Effects for this purpose. Right now, any solution is appreciated — currently considering to write my own program for this ;)